# Do the GNU Rules about Nonfree Javascript apply to Server-Side JS?

Tags: website, gnu, freedoms

The page [The Javascript Trap](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/javascript-trap.html) describes guidelines for making JS code free/libre. I know that this is considered mandatory in web pages, but do the same rules apply to server-side JS? For example, do I need to add license comments in my Node or Deno scripts? If so, is there something like LibreJS for the server-side?

Comment: If you're running JS server-side, then you will know where it comes from and should know what its license is. So I don't really understand your question.

Comment: @curiousdannii I think this question asks about voluntary compliance with the FSF's annotation guidelines for JavaScript, for the benefit of users of one's web service. It doesn't matter that the operator of the service knows this information, since the substance of the question is how/whether to communicate with information via annotation (i.e., the "method by which a nontrivial JavaScript program in a web page can state ..." in the linked article)

Comment: @Apsillers Right, but server-side JS isn't really a "web page" in any sense.

Comment: @curiousdannii I think that's more or less the answer to this question: the guidelines being linked to are not applicable to the server-side case in question, so there do not exist annotation guidelines for this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a word: no.

The FSF advocates for LibreJS annotations because of the special place web browser scripting plays in the lives of web users. The *linga franca* for browser scripting happens to be JavaScript.

[Server-side code gets its own consideration from the FSF](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/who-does-that-server-really-serve.en.html) but the use of JavaScript as a server-side language does not merit more consideration than any other language. In other words, if you have a service written in JavaScript and you rewrote it in another language, the FSF's recommendations pertaining to those two implementations would be identical.